# How to compile libpng.so for Android

Tags: android-ndk, libpng

I want to compile an old version of libpng for the Android project, such as version 1.2.33.

And I need to cross compile using the NDK toolchain in a Linux environment to obtain the dynamic link library （libpng.so）

I'm not quite sure what to do, many tutorials are about obtaining libpng.a, which is not what I need.

Looking forward to your answer, thank you!

In libpng-1.2.33:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --enable-shared
```

prompt:

```
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `arm-linux-androideabi': system `androideabi' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub arm-linux-androideabi failed
```